# mongoose aggregate lookup give only one object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

An example document in my collection:

```
{
    _id: "5e88dba0cae7632fe49226db"
    dishes: (2) ["5e8850b9980477519800a928", "5e8c838ee0b3a44e3491d347"]
    name: "test"
    dateOfMenu: "2020-04-05T09:21:07.000Z"
    __v: 0
    createdAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z"
    updatedAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z"
}
```

I'm using the following aggregation:

```
Menu.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            dateOfMenu: {"$gte": nextWeekDateSunday, "$lt": nextWeekDateFriday}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'dishes',
            localField: 'dishes',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'dishes'
        }
    }
])
```

The issue is that it returns only the first row from `dishes` list always and not all the array.

Comment: The syntax of the `$lookup` is fine, make sure you have the matching documents in the other collection, also make sure the `_id`'s are matching to the `dishes`, it seems you're trying to lookup using `string` and not `ObjectId`

Comment: its a ObjectId  not string (thats what i get in the client side),
and the object is in the collection

Answer (score 0):

you have to do `$unwind` step before the `$lookup` to expand the dishes array into a stream of `Menu` documents

```
Menu.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { } // add your search object here
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$dishes' // unwind this dishes array to expand this array to a stream of Menu documents
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'dishes',
            localField: 'dishes',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'dish'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$dish' // this to convert the array of one object to be an object
    }
])
```

this will return an array of documents, each document will have an array of dishes, but this array will contain only one dish object, so we can use `$unwind` again after the `$lookup` to convert that array of only one object to be an object, and we can name it dish now instead of dishes

the output will be something like that

```
{
    _id: "5e88dba0cae7632fe49226db",
    dish: {
        _id: "5e8850b9980477519800a928",
        name: "Spagetti", // assuming the dish model has a name
        // all the other properties in the dish Model
    },
    name: "test",
    dateOfMenu: "2020-04-05T09:21:07.000Z",
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z"
}
{
    _id: "5e88dba0cae7632fe49226db",
    dish: {
        _id: "5e8c838ee0b3a44e3491d347",
        mame: "Burger", // assuming the dish model has a name
        // all the other properties in the dish Model
    },
    name: "test",
    dateOfMenu: "2020-04-05T09:21:07.000Z",
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z",
    updatedAt: "2020-04-04T19:10:24.814Z"
}
```

if you need to group all the documents that have the same menu id, so you have the menu and all its dishes in the same document, we can do some grouping using the `$group`

so the query will be like that

```
Menu.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { } // add your search object here
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$dishes' // unwind this dishes array to expand this array to a stream of Menu documents
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'dishes',
            localField: 'dishes',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'dish'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$dish' // this to convert the array of one object to be an object
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id', // the _id of the menu
            name: { $first: '$name' }, // name of the menu
            createdDate: { $first: '$createdDate' }, // createdDate of the menu
            dishes: { // dishes array in this menu
                $addToSet: '$dish' // here we used addToSet, as here we have an array of dishes, so push the dish to that array
            }
        }
    }
])
```

the result will be something like that

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e88dba0cae7632fe49226db"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2020-04-05T22:00:00Z"),
    "dishes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e8850b9980477519800a928"),
            "name" : "Spaggetti",
            "main" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e8c838ee0b3a44e3491d347"),
            "name" : "Burger",
            "main" : true
        }
    ]
}
```